# How does Windows 10 File History determine file-changes?

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-backup, file-history

Does Windows 10 File History use hashes of the content of files to determine changes or just the modification date of the file or log all modifications somewhere or something else?

edit: And will File History make a backup of a file in case of a flipped bit?

Answer (score 2):

> File History takes advantage of a feature built into the NTFS file system called the change journal. Essentially, when any change is made to a file or folder on your hard disk, the change journal is updated with a description of the change and the name of the file or folder. So to determine which files need to be backed up, File History simply consults the NTFS change journal. Using the change journal is fast and efficient and won't suck up tons of system resources like running a conventional backup routine does.

[Source](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/protect-your-data-files-with-windows-10s-enhanced-file-history-tool/)

Comment: Will File History make a backup in case of a flipped bit?